# A USB stick isn't visible anywhere but in dmesg

Tags: arch-linux, mount, usb, usb-drive

I'm plugging in a usb stick and isn't not getting mounted and kind of invisible.

```
$ sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 178.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   256M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0    50G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0 128.6G  0 part /home
$ dmesg
[159171.366480] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd

$ ls -al /dev/sd*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Sep 15 10:48 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 Sep 15 10:48 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 2 Sep 15 10:48 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 3 Sep 15 10:48 /dev/sda3
```

What's up with it?

Comment: Have you installed a kernel update but not rebooted?

Comment: @Wieland, I don't know, I've logged out but it didn't help.

Comment: logging out wouldn't help. Can you post the output of `pacman -Qi linux` and `uname -a`?